# Wrapping a web project in a solution file, and CVS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, solution

This could quite possibly be the dumbest question ever asked.  Our client wants us to have a Solution file (one .sln and .suo) neatly put into 1 directory higher than the actual web project.  And we don't even have a Web Project file, it's just a website setup in IIS that we open from Visual Studio (2008 in case it matters) by clicking on File -> Open Website and browsing to the root directory (c:\src\clientname\src\web\ -- that's there choice, not mine).

Now, how would I wrap this existing web project, without a project file, into a new blank solution located in c:\src\clientname\src\?

I love .Net, but sometimes the configuration hoops get me all twisted up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as opening the website folder, File > Save As and pick where you'd like the SLN file to sit. The SLN file does not need to be relative to the website itself.

Comment: That was close -- when I opened it up, I didn't have a choice of "File > Save As...".  However, after I added an existing project via "File > Existing Project", THEN I had a solution, and I could choose to save the solution where I wanted with a name that I wanted.

Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Sure thing! Another approach to this would be to open Visual Studio go to File > New Project then Other Project Types > Blank Visual Studio Solution. Pick a name, hit okay, then add the Existing Website.

Comment: Doh!  That would have been perfect.  I couldn't figure out how to make a blank one, forgot about that.  I went way down a bad path that the solution I had made kept wanting to be "upgraded" every time I opened it.  Fun.